# Additional rows needed in SQL view

Tags: mysql, postgresql, join, view

I have the following SQL tables, and require a solution compatible with both MySQL and Postgresql

```
create table price_level (
 id serial primary key,
 name varchar(200)
);

create table product (
 id serial primary key,
 name varchar(200),
 base numeric not null,
 vat int not null
);

create table product_price (
 id serial primary key,
 base numeric,
 vat numeric,
 product_id int not null references product(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
 price_level_id int not null references price_level(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
 unique(product_id,price_level_id)
);
```

For the SQL structure above I've created a view:

```
create view view_product as
select
    p.id as product_id,
    coalesce(pp.base, p.base) as base,
    coalesce(pp.vat, p.vat) as vat,
    pp.price_level_id

from
    product as p
left join
    product_price as pp on pp.product_id=p.id
;
```

These are sample data:

Table **price_level**

```
id  name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

Table **product**

```
id  name    base    vat
1   Test    100     20
```

Table **product_price**

```
id   base   vat  product_id price_level_id
1    NULL   NULL 1          1
2    200    NULL 1          2
3    NULL   10   1          3
```

Output of the view **view_product** is:

```
product_id   base    vat  price_level_id
1            100    20    1
1            200    20    2
1            100    10    3
```

... and the question is: *How do I get output like this?*:

```
product_id   base   vat    price_level_id
1            100    20    1
1            200    20    2
1            100    10    3
1            100    20    4
1            100    20    5
```

As you see in the example above I need to get **D** and **E** price_level as additional rows. How do I create such view/join? It should have good performance also because tables can get big with additional price levels.

Thanks for help.

Comment: why don't you add the two missing rows into the product_price table, analogous to its first row?

Comment: @Strawberry It should be compatible with both RDBMS - PostgreSQL and MySQL. That's why I tagged it that way. It is absolutely enough if the answer is compatibile for just one of them. I just need a clue how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @luksch that's the problem. I can't. Input is not build that way so I need to have a view with the output I presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use following approach, cross join tables price_level and product. Then just lookup if override exists in product_price table.

```
SELECT
  product.id as product_id,
  IFNULL(product_price.base, product.base) as `base`,
  IFNULL(product_price.vat, product.vat) as `vat`,
  price_level.id as price_level_id
FROM price_level
CROSS JOIN product
LEFT JOIN product_price ON 
  product_price.price_level_id = price_level.id AND
  product_price.product_id = product.id
WHERE product.id = 1
ORDER BY product.id, price_level.id
```

just remember to use product.id and not product_id in WHERE conditions

Comment: This solution seems to be the best from the performance view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `union` to add those records from `price_level` table that do not have corresponding record in `product_price` table for a certain product:

```
select
    p.id as product_id,
    coalesce(pp.base, p.base) as base,
    coalesce(pp.vat, p.vat) as vat,
    pp.price_level_id

from
    product as p
left join
    product_price as pp on pp.product_id=p.id
union distinct
select
    p.id as product_id,
    p.base,
    p.vat,
    pl.price_level_id
from
    price_level pl
join
    product as p
where (p.id, pl.id) not in (select product_id, price_level_id from product_price)
```

Comment: This one seems good to me and it works. I will benchmark the performance with few milion products and hundreds or thousands price levels. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
create view view_product as
select
p.id as product_id,
coalesce(pp.base, p.base) as base,
coalesce(pp.vat, p.vat) as vat,
coalesce(pp.price_level_id,pl.id) --modified row
from
product as p
left join
product_price as pp on pp.product_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN price_level pl on pp.price_level_id=pl.id -- modified row
;
```

(not tested, but for sure you have to catch the price levels from the properly table)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN price_level` means that everything from the other tables will be in the resultset, but only matching rows from the price_level table will be included. This means that price levels with id 4 and 5 will not be included.